# Error pushing variables to template in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to push an array object to the Template generated by the HTMLService, so that I can populate a drop down box.

My function `showSidebar()` is called in the `onOpen()` function.

showSideBar()

```
/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 */
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar')
      .setTitle('Generate Reports');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

the contents of the HTML file Sidebar.html is

```
<div class="sidebar branding-below">
  <form>
    <div class="block col-contain">
      <div class="block form-group">
         <label for="client-dd"><b>Client Name</b></label><br />
         <select id="client-dd" class="width-100">
         <? var data = getUniqueCustomers();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            { 
               var val = data[i]; 
               var v = val[0]; ?>
               <option value='<?!= v ?>'>
                  <?!=v ?>
               </option>
         <? } ?>
         </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

the function `getUniqueCustomers()` ( I know it works because I have tested it)  is as follows

```
function getUniqueCustomers(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rangeVals = sheet.getRange("E2:E");
  var x = ArrayLib.unique(rangeVals.getValues());
  return x;
}
```

However for some reason I see the following in the sidebar

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use templated HTML - for this you need to use **HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile()** method instead of .createHtmlOutputFromFile(). [Full documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)